# add <br/> take after </span> with jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm having a twitter feed automatically added by a script. I want to add a `<br/>` with jquery in it. Now it's like this

```
    <ul id="twitter_update_list">
    <li><span>something</span> <a  href="#">about 4 hours ago</a></li>
    <li><span>something</span> <a  href="#">about 6 hours ago</a></li>
    </ul>
```

I want to add a `<br/>` after each `</span>` with jquery. so that its like this

```
 <ul id="twitter_update_list">
    <li><span>something</span><br/> <a  href="#">about 4 hours ago</a></li>
    <li><span>something</span><br/> <a  href="#">about 6 hours ago</a></li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: I... I just have to ask... Why? ... I mean, why not include the `<br/>` in the HTML in the first place and use JS to do this...?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use [`.after()`](http://api.jquery.com/after/) to insert an element after each the selector matched, like this:

```
$("#twitter_update_list span").after("<br />");
```

[You can test it out here](http://www.jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/zEdQP/). The result is...well, exactly what you have in the question :)

Comment: @esafwan, Answer to your question would be this, but I would prefer @balexandre's answer more :D No offence @Nick

Comment: @Starx - *If* it meets the needs I agree, go with CSS, but it may not...since it's not the same result.

Answer (score 5):

why messing up in Javasript while you can do the same with CSS?

```
#twitter_update_list li span { display: block; margin-bottom: 10px; }
```

Comment: I agree, placing presentation markup into content is a no no. Using CSS to style content = best practise

Comment: Making the `<span>` a block isn't the same...you should note this, he may have any kind if styling beside it, this forces it on it's own line completely.

Comment: @Nick then he just need to use `float: left;` and style everything correctly... should never be script handled!

Comment: `float: left;` is different as well, this would take it to the beginning of the line, or different compared to other floats...my point was simply you can't always drop in a replacement, it depends what *other* styling is going on.

Comment: @Nick my point is also simple, styling should be on CSS side never on code, and worst, never on javascript :o)

Answer (score 1):

If it only look that matter, then use css:

```
#twitter_update_list>li>span{
    display:block}
```

Or if you really want jQuery:

```
$('#twitter_update_list>li>span').after('<br/>');
```

Answer (score 0):

`$("#twitter_update_list span").after("<br />");`